# Ionic installation issue

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to install ionic.

I had set up node.js, Java SDK. and ionic via node.js

When I tried to run ionic from cmd, I got the below error.

```
>     C:\Users\aaa>ionic info
>     module.js:472
>         throw err;
>         ^
>     
>     Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\aaa\AppData\Roaming\npm\de_modules\ionic\bin\ionic'
>         at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
>         at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
>         at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
>         at run (bootstrap_node.js:423:7)
>         at startup (bootstrap_node.js:147:9)
>         at bootstrap_node.js:538:3
>     
>     C:\Users\aaa>
```

Why ı am getting this message ?

I have tried to re install several times. but the result is the same.

Comment: how did you install ionic?

Comment: Write down your all steps which u have done so far . Which version u r using ?

Comment: I have installed JDK 1.8.0 sucessfully and added to path.
I have installed node.js v7.9.0 Current sucessfully.
I have insteled cordova via cmd "npm install -g cordova"
I have installed ionic via cmd "npm install -g ionic"

then ı am trying ionic info. 
I have got this error. ?

C:\Users\aaa\AppData\Roaming\npm\de_modules\ionic\bin\ionic
why this path  
..\de_modules\ 
instead of 
..\node_modules\

Comment: did u install any dummy project and tried ionic serve ?

Answer (score 0):

I have Found the problem.

My ionic.cmd

```
@IF EXIST "%~dp0\node.exe" (
  "%~dp0\node.exe"  "%~dp0\de_modules\ionic\bin\ionic" %*
) ELSE (
  @SETLOCAL
  @SET PATHEXT=%PATHEXT:;.JS;=;%
  node  "%~dp0\de_modules\ionic\bin\ionic" %*
)
```

there has invalid path.

```
@IF EXIST "%~dp0\node.exe" (
  "%~dp0\node.exe"  "%~dp0\node_modules\ionic\bin\ionic" %*
) ELSE (
  @SETLOCAL
  @SET PATHEXT=%PATHEXT:;.JS;=;%
  node  "%~dp0\node_modules\ionic\bin\ionic" %*
)
```

I changed like thar. The Problem solved. Thanks.